# Django model validate a ManyToMany field before adding

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that looks somewhat like this:

```
class Passenger(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Flight(models.Model):
    capacity = models.IntegerField()
    passengers = models.ManyToManyField(Passenger)
```

Before adding a new passenger to the flight I would like to validate whether the number of passengers is not going to exceed the capacity. I was wondering what would be the best way to go about this.

Obviously I could manually check the number of passengers before adding a new one, but maybe there is some support in django? I tried writing a validator, but wasn't sure how to do it.

Comment: *check the number of passengers before adding a new one* as you said

Answer (score 4):

According to Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) you can listen to the **m2m_changed** signal, which will trigger **pre_add** and **post_add** actions.

> Using add() with a many-to-many relationship, however, will not call
>   any save() methods (the bulk argument doesn’t exist), but rather
>   create the relationships using QuerySet.bulk_create(). If you need to
>   execute some custom logic when a relationship is created, listen to
>   the m2m_changed signal, which will trigger pre_add and post_add
>   actions.

Answer (score 3):

According to @M.Void answer – Code Example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MyModel(models.Model):
    m2mField = models.ManyToManyField('self')
    m2mFieldLimit = 2

def m2mField_changed(sender,**kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    if len(instance.m2mField.all()) >= instance.m2mFieldLimit :
        raise ValidationError(f'Max number of records is {instance.m2mFieldLimi}')

m2m_changed.connect(m2mField_changed,sender=MyModel.m2mField.through)
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the `clean` method on the model to do the check you want:

```
class Passenger(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # clean gets called automatically by other things, so we can't always
        # expect flight_id to be provided
        if 'flight_id' in kwargs:
            flight = Flight.objects.get(pk=kwargs['flight_id'])
            if flight.passengers.all().count() >= flight.capacity:
                # flight is full!
                raise ValidationError
        super(Passenger, self).clean()

class Flight(models.Model):
    capacity = models.IntegerField()
    passengers = models.ManyToManyField(Passenger)
```

Note that to do this, you will have to pass in the flight ID when validating the passenger:

```
f = Flight.objects.get(...)
p = Passenger(name='First', surname='Last')
try:
    p.clean(flight_id=f.id) # full_clean calls clean, among other validations
    p.save()
except ValidationError as e:
    # do something to handle the error
```

Note that it is possible in multi-threaded applications for something to get validated successfully, but still fail to save in a race condition. You would need to add additional code to handle that.

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) for details on model validation.

Comment: Thanks @fiveclubs for answering! I tried implementing your solution, but I have problem with passing the arguments to clean function. I can't access the 'flight_id' from kwargs.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work it says `clean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flight_id'`

Comment: OK, that makes sense, since the base `clean` method takes no arguments. I've updated the answer to call the superclass clean method properly. This illustrates that the model validation is really not designed to handle this extra argument, and seems to be used more for static validation. As long as you're careful, though, it seems like a valid use of overriding the clean method.